# Unable to use Angular UI typeahead with Yammer AutoComplete request

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, yammer

I'm building an AngularJs application using Yammer JS SDK. Current application calls the Yammer AutoComplete rest api service and uses Angular-UI Bootstrap's Typeahead library to populate the autocomplete results on the webpage. Unfortunately, i'm getting length error from Typeahead library as it is trying to find an array in the returned function. I know how to return a result array as promise using AngularJS $http service, but i couldn't figure out how to implement the same using yam.platform.request call. Below is the source code for the method that i'm calling for auto completion.

```
 $scope.autoComplete = function (val) {
   var users = []; 
   yam.platform.getLoginStatus(
      function(response) {
       if(response.authResponse){
           return yam.platform.request({
           url: "autocomplete/ranked", 
           method: "GET",
           data: {
                  "models":"user:15",
                  "prefix": val 
           },
          success: function (response) {
                     if (response.user) {
                         users = [];
                         angular.forEach(response.user, function(user){
                          users.push(user);
                     });
                     return users; 
                    }; 
          },
          error: function (error) {
                    users = [];
                    console.error(error);
                    return users; 
                 }
          });

       }
    });
   };
```

I'm receiving the below error in the response,

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for the above problem using angularjs promises. This is a work around for the above problem.

```
    $scope.autoComplete = function(val) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $scope.autoCompleteSearch(val, deferred, function(users){
                deferred.resolve(users);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        $scope.autoCompleteSearch = function (val, deferred, callback) {
              return yam.platform.getLoginStatus(
                function(response) {
                  if(response.authResponse){
                         return yam.platform.request({
                            url: "autocomplete/ranked", 
                            method: "GET",
                            data: {
                              "models":"user:15",
                              "prefix": val        
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                                 var users = []; 
                                if (response.user) {
                                    users = [];
                                    angular.forEach(response.user, function(user){
                                        users.push(user);
                                    });
                                    callback(users); 
                                };                       
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                              var users = [];
                              console.error(error);
                              callback(users); 
                            }
                    });

                  }
            });
        };
```

Hope it helps for anyone having this issue.

Regards.